# Alternative to CSS3 transform: rotate(xdeg) in CSS2 or Javascript to rotate text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My problem is that I use a html to pdf generator (acts_as_flying_saucer) that support CSS2 and javascript but not css3 so I can't use the `transform: rotate(-90deg)` (of course with different engines like webkit and stuff).

I tried PDFKit and Wicked_pdf but they didn't have full CSS2 support whereas I needed the `position: fixed` to set my footers on all pages to the bottom of the page.

SO my question is if there is a way to get vertical text with either CSS2 and / or Javascript /JQuery? CSS3 is out of the question unfortunately. :(

Comment: I'm sorry but without 'transform: rotate' in any way this can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

In IE the `writing-mode` is available.

```
<span style="writing-mode: tb-rl;">CSS2?</span>
```

See more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: or `-ms-writing-mode` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531187(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: I need it to work in all web-browsers not only IE. I don't even have IE because I run Linux and I don't want it to only work in IE.

Comment: There are some -moz -extensions for Mozilla browsers. I tried some, but I didn't get them work. Reference is in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible without `rotate`. I don't know just crazy idea using canvas.
http://jsfiddle.net/LBsuQ/

Comment: It was a good idea and I tried it but acts_as_flying_saucer didn't support the canvas. :(

Comment: Then you can't do anything. Just another crazy idea for simple text lables etc generate images on the server side..